# Change Image/svg to Correctly Show Landscape Or Portrait on Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

when i change the Window size from landscape to portrait the page doesnt refresh
correctly

how can i change the code for the the page to show landscape or portrait svg with correct size

the landscape.svg is slightly different from the portrait.svg

please help

```
    <script>
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
    {

        // Portrait
        //alert ("Resized..P");
        document.write( '<object id=\"svg-objectp\" data=\"car1-portrait.svg\" type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>' );
        document.getElementById("svg-objectp").style.width = "100%"; 
        document.getElementById("svg-objectp").style.height = "auto"; 

        }else{

        // Landscape
        //alert ("Resized..L");
        document.write( '<object id=\"svg-objectl\" data=\"car1-landscape.svg\" type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>' );
        document.getElementById("svg-objectl").style.width = "100%"; 
        document.getElementById("svg-objectl").style.height = "auto"; 

    }
    </script>

    http://www.qurantour.com/car/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work because your javascript code gets executed only once, you need an event here to make it work:

```
    <script>
    window.onresize = function() {
      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth)
      {

      // Portrait
      //alert ("Resized..P");
      document.write( '<object id=\"svg-objectp\" data=\"car1-portrait.svg\" 
      type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>' );
      document.getElementById("svg-objectp").style.width = "100%"; 
      document.getElementById("svg-objectp").style.height = "auto"; 

      }else{

      // Landscape
      //alert ("Resized..L");
      document.write( '<object id=\"svg-objectl\" data=\"car1-landscape.svg\" 
      type=\"image/svg+xml\"></object>' );
      document.getElementById("svg-objectl").style.width = "100%"; 
      document.getElementById("svg-objectl").style.height = "auto"; 

    }
  }
  </script
```